# Angular 2 custom component to show multiple buttons based on page requirement

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to implement a custom button component with Angular 2 which should show buttons as per page requirement.

For example if on one of the page I want to show save,reset and cancel buttons.
And on other page I just want to show Save button using the same component.

How do I achieve that?

I am trying to do in following way

In my component :

```
@Input() saveButtonRequired = boolean = false,
@Input() resetButtonRequired = boolean = false,
@Input() cancelButtonRequired = boolean = false,
```

In my page:

```
buttons-components 
saveButtonRequired="true" 
cancelButtonRequired="false" 
resetButtonRequired="true" 
buttons-component
```

Note: buttons-component is my selector name

Comment: Your template code (`buttons-components`) is missing mark up. You may want to do something about that to make this a little less confusing. Like adding the actual template code (HTML).

Comment: On your button-component template where you declare your buttons ad *ngIf="saveButtonRequired"

Comment: @jmw5598 Thanks!